# Css is not working when I tried to style anything. I added with semantic-ui

Tags: css, semantic-ui

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>My Travel App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="ui fixed inverted menu">
        <div class="ui container">
            <div class="header item"><i style="font-size: 20px;" class="edit icon"></i>Blog Site</div>
            <a href="/" class="item">Home</a>
            <a href="/blogs/new" class="item">New Post</a>
        </div>
    </div>
<p class="sample"> I can style here with css in app.css</p>
```

Can anyone help with the css/semantic-ui problem, please? 
When I use style tag in the file as above it is working but if try to style something in my app.css file it does not work. I can style something else that I did not use semantic-ui in but I cannot style anything that has something from semantic-ui.

For example: I can style the class "sample" in my app.css file but cannot style class "item".
Thanks!

Comment: This question gets asked ad nauseum on SO and the multitude of same answers you can try can be found with a simple search of SO and/or the internet. [Here's the most recent one I saw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58827762/im-having-trouble-with-applying-css-to-my-html)

Answer (score 0):

Its because of your files precedence in `header`, it read line by line first come first serve.

Always add your custom file in the end of header so that your custom style's overwrite default styles.

Replace below code

```
 <head>
        <title>My Travel App</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
            href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/app.css">
    </head>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Move `semantic.min.css` in top of `app.css`...

```
<head>
    <title>My Travel App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/app.css">

</head>
```

Comment: Please, provide a working example, not just put a comment